# Doing rather complicated calculations on each group after groupby

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like

```
import pandas as pd
A = ['x' , 'x', 'y', 'y', 'y']
B = [1, 3, 2, 1, 4]
C = [2, 3, 7, 2, 1]
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : A, 'B' : B, 'C' : C })
df
```

and unfortunately I couldn't do this calculation on each group after `df.groupby(['A'])`: multiply `B` elementwise with `C` elements and sum them and divide this by sum of elements of `B` and so heve the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['x', 'y'], '(B*C)/B' : [(1*2 + 3*3)/(1+3) , (2*7+1*2+4*1)/(2+1+4)]})
df1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do an `apply`:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: (x['B']*x['C']).sum()/x['B'].sum())
```

Or similarly:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: np.average(x['C'],weights=x['B']) )
```

Output:

```
A
x    2.750000
y    2.857143
dtype: float64
```